# Bootstrap media inside drop down menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

If i place a media object inside Bootstrap drop down, the menu should expand in width to accommodate media. In the example i wrote in the JSiddle, the heading and text below heading should not wrap to new line.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown" id="account">
        <form action="/tracker/logout" method="post">
            <button type="button" id="accountHolder" class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Lokesh<span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <div class="media">
                        <img class="media-object pull-left" alt="" src="http://www.google.com/homepage/images/google_favicon_64.png">
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <a><h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4></a>
                                This is some sample text
                            </div>
                      </div> 
                 </li>
              </ul> 
          </form>               
    </li>
</ul>
```

please make output window larger to see menu on right corner as i want menu on right side.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12500/

Thanks

Comment: this is because `h4` takes full width so it makes other text to go on next line

Comment: Atleast h4 content should be in single line

Comment: the `width` and `height` of image is causing a problem if you give `width` and `height` of image the `h4` will be in single line

Comment: try `style="display: inline-flex;" ` for `media-body` div

Comment: @Amitsingh Flex, not supported for all browsers